# jQuery - Loading two script in one page, one failed after the other was launched

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 3 select boxes : day, timetable and offers.

If we change day select value : timetable AND offers  will change too.

If we change timetable : only offers select will change.

I have two ajax calls in order to do that :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //If we change the day
    $('#daysOffers').change(function(){
        var selectedDate = $('#daysOffers option:selected').val();
        console.log(selectedDate);

        $.ajax({
            url:  '<?= Yii::app()->createUrl('place/orderOffersBySelectedDate') ?>',
            type: 'GET',
            data: 'placeId='+<?=$placeId ?>+'&cityId='+<?= $cityId ?>+'&selectedDate='+selectedDate+'',
            success: function(data) { 
                $('#timeAndOffers').empty();
                $('#timeAndOffers').append(data);
            }
        });
    });

    //If we change the timetable
    $('#timetableOffers').change(function(){
        console.log('Changing time');
        var selectedDate = $('#daysOffers option:selected').val();
        var start = $('#timetableOffers option:selected').data("timestart");
        var end = $('#timetableOffers option:selected').data("timeend");

        $.ajax({
            url:  '<?= Yii::app()->createUrl('place/orderOffersBySelectedDate') ?>',
            type: 'GET',
            data: 'placeId='+<?=$placeId ?>+'&cityId='+<?= $cityId ?>+'&selectedDate='+selectedDate+'&startTime='+start+'&endTime='+end+'',
            success: function(data) { 
                $('#offersByDay').empty();
                $('#offersByDay').append(data);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

First scenario :

- If I change daysOffer (the day) the call works.
- Then, if I change timetableOffers the call failed, like the change event was not detected.

Second scenario :

- If I change timetableOffers the call works (event detected)
- Then if I change de daysOffer the call works too (event detected)
- If i change timetableOffers again, the call failed.. But changing daysOffer still works

What's going on and what can I do to fix it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried jQuery `on()`? Not sure but dynamic options may not trigger a `change()` as the event is bound too early. `on()` can delegate this behavior from the parent => `parent.on('change', '#daysOffers', function(){})`

Comment: Can you show your HTML associated with the jquery event bindings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wild guess because i don't see your HTML:

Is your `#timeAndOffers` the element containing both `#timetableOffers` and `offersByDay`?

If so, in the callback method for `$('#daysOffers').change` you are emptying it and reappending `data` inside it, thus recreating the `#timetableOffers` select.

The event listener you appended to `#timetableOffers` with `.change` does will not fire when the new select is changed, since the DOM element it was attached to no longer exists.

You have two options then:

- Reattach the event listener at the end of `$('#daysOffers').change`'s callback, or
- Use [`jquery.on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/), which will have the event handler be called even when the event is fired by DOM elements that are not present at the time of attaching.

I think the best solution is the second one, which will require you to change

```
$('#timetableOffers').change(function(){
```

to

```
$(document).on('change', '#timetableOffers', function(){
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! It works like a charm ! 
I did not know this subtility !

I used jQuery.on !

Thanks to all of you.